# How to automate homebrew installation?

Tags: ruby, unix, homebrew

I'm deploying stuff on some unix machines and I need to get home-brew installed without any user prompt. Currently, the only way I found to install home-brew is to run this ruby script:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"
```

But this has user prompts and cannot be fully automated. Can anyone suggest a way to install this without user prompts?

Comment: I didn't even know homebrew would work on non-osx systems. You could always modify the script.

Comment: Since Homebrew is "The missing package manager for OS X", and it's designed to allow installation of Linux code on Mac OS using Mac-equivalent libraries, I'd say it's being used in a non-supported way. Whether it can actually install libraries after being shoehorned into Linux is another question.

Answer (score 5):

The current implementation of the [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/index.html) installation script will prompt the User if stdin is set to TTY. By redirecting stdin to /dev/null, the installer can be run without user intervention.

```
'ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)" < /dev/null'
```

Enjoy Peteris Krumins' awesome reference: [Bash Redirections Cheat Sheet](http://www.catonmat.net/download/bash-redirections-cheat-sheet.pdf).

Comment: Unfortunately the ruby install script is now deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know when this was added, but these days you can prepend the install command with `NONINTERACTIVE=1` to avoid prompts:

```bash
NONINTERACTIVE=1 ruby -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

[Documentation](https://github.com/Homebrew/install/#install-homebrew-on-macos-or-linux)

Answer (score 0):

You can use e.g. puppet(http://puppetlabs.com/puppet/what-is-puppet) and e.g. this puppet modul https://forge.puppetlabs.com/bjoernalbers/homebrew

Comment: Looks interesting but I just want to execute an install script on local machine and I do not want to complicate things.

Answer (score 0):

The Homebrew install script "just" checks permissions and clones the git repository. If you're on Linux, use [Linuxbrew](http://brew.sh/linuxbrew/). Note the advice on the Linuxbrew home page that you can install by doing

```
git clone https://github.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew.git ~/.linuxbrew
```

and, in e.g. ~/.bash_profile:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

to get everything set up.

You can do something similar on OS X. Make sure you have your filesystem permissions in order and `git clone https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew.git /usr/local` (or wherever) and set up your PATH.